# I'm not able to install mod_wsgi even tho im installed visual c++

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I wanna install mod_wsigi (pip install mod_wsgi) for my local apache server on windows for that i allreday installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64) - 14.16.27027. still after that im not able to install mod.

I will be very thankful to resole this problem.

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='
```

"'"'C:\Users\Jovid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b193h_8j\mod-wsgi\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'
"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'ex
ec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Jovid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2jv00ikh\install-record.txt' --single-version-
externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: c:\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi
    copying src__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
    copying src\server\management__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
    copying docs_build\html__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win32-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.m
icrosoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'C:\Users\Jovid\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b193h_8j\mod-wsgi\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);co
de=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --rec
ord 'C:\Users\Jovid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2jv00ikh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --com
pile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Jovid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b193h_8j\mod-wsgi\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message, and its solution, is in the text you included in your question:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

This is **not** the same as the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable. The Visual C++ Redistributable only includes libraries; the Visual C++ Build Tools are a full toolchain, including a C++ compiler.

Comment: while i was trying to install Visual C++ Build Tools it asking me to update my windows 8 to 8.1 is it any way to avoid this update requirement ?

Comment: No. Windows 8.0 has been unsupported by Microsoft since January 2016. (Windows 8.1 is itself currently under Extended Support, which will end in January 2023.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install MS Visual C++ Build Tools but the problem is still there. Try to download the compiled module from: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) and install the .whl successfully.